# How to access accessors in python Class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to access the accessor `getSentence()` however I am getting the error that

```
AttributeError: 'Sentence' object has no attribute '_string'
```

I looked at many libraries and they said the right way to return it is with

```
self._
```

Here is my code:

```
class Sentence:
    def __init__(self, string):
        self.string = string
    def getSentence(self):
        return self._string
    def getWords(self):
        return self._aList
    def getLength(self):
        return len(self._string)
    def getNumWords(self):
        return len(self._string.split())


hippo = Sentence("hello world")
hippo.getSentence()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `__init__` you assign to `self.string`, not `self._string`. Simply correct that to `self._string` *or* rename the attribute you access in `getSentence()` to `self.string`.

That said, you don't really *need* an accessor here. If you leave the name as `string`, you can just use `hippo.string` and be done with it. Accessors are not really that useful if all they do is return the value of an attribute.

Comment: It is working now but it did not return the sentence. Can you please check for me why ?

Comment: @Mozein: it *does* return the sentence, but you are ignoring that return value. Perhaps you wanted to use `print(hippo.getSentence())`?